# How to programmatically setup a dialup connection

Tags: windows, networking, regedit

I have a question - is there some way to set a login and password for a certain dial up connection?
I am able to create a Dial Up connection, however I'm unable to "save" the password and login into Windows (so it would remember them).

Please note that I want to do it without the Windows GUI, ideally just using regedit/cmd or windows default tools (that can be executed from cmd).

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this for Windows CE so I used the remote registry editor to compare before and after adding a dial up connection. I found the settings in [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Comm\RasBook\ConnectionAddedByMe], hopefully you can do the same locally.

Comment: Im not working on the problem anymore, so I wont have the opportunity to check it, but it could work (though I tried to do the registry check before/after and didnt have much success with it)